# Google Pay android integration don’t see my app

Tags: flutter, google-pay

I have already done Google Pay integration in my Flutter app. Also I already have confirmed merchant profile . I already tested Google Pay on test environment and all work. But after deployed app on Play Market I have OR_BIBED_11 popup and app not appeared in my android integration list . Mentioned that I already have 1 app for this profile . What should I do or what I do wrong .

Thanks a lot

After research I found required to send app for production approval . But I don’t really understand where can I do that . In my business console I have only “add Web integration “

Comment: make sure you use the same account to login to the business console as you use to login to the play console

Comment: Yes , this is the same account which I use . Issue is that I don’t understand where can I get production approval from Google pay console for android app

Comment: If you use the same account as you used for the play console you should see your app in the pay & wallet console. here is an example: https://i.ibb.co/rcHY6xK/Screenshot-2023-10-27-at-09-38-48.png

Comment: Let me clarify , role in Google pay & wallet console must be owner , or administrator will enough ? Cause app is already published but i unable to see my app in this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gyus. As was mentioned by [@Domi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789738/domi), check if your email , which you use in Google Business console is in a list of emails from Google Play console.

I have no access for Busines console by email from Play console and thats was an issue. Even if u don't integrate Google Pay api in your project, after publishing your app it will appear in the integration list if it's Android app.

Thanks a lot.